# SQL join two tables and create new column

Tags: sql, hana

I have two tables on HANA which are built of the same columns. Table A contains IDs which are also in table B but it also contains IDs which are not in table B. Table B may also contain IDs which are not in table A.

I want to join both tables. The result should list all entries which are either in table A or in table B. However, if one ID is part of both tables, there should only be one entry of the ID in the result.

To differ the usage of the IDs, there should be a new column in the result. It should display one of the following values:

- "Table A" if the ID is only in table A
- "Table B" if the ID is only in table B
- "Table A+B" if the ID is in both tables

Here is some sketch about what I want to achieve:

[image]

I appreciate every help!

Best Regards.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I added some sample data.

Comment: What if Table B row with ID 2 had Lion instead of cat?

Comment: That's not possible. Same ID = Same Description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
       (case when a.id is null then 'B only'
             when b.id is null then 'A only'
             else 'Both'
        end) as which_table,
       . . .  -- whatever other columns you want
from a full join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: from first condition: don't we get `B only` if  both `a.id,b.id` is null so need condition for `b.id` ??

Comment: @Susang . . . First, the question only needs these three categories.  Second, ids not in both tables cannot be in the result set (they have to come from somewhere).  If `id` can be `NULL` in either table, then the problem is a bit different.  This assumes that `id` is not `NULL`. If you are interested in the case where they can be `NULL`, feel free to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION ALL`, then `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select id, description, max(ta), max(tb)
from
(
    select id, description, 'A' as ta, null as tb from tablea
    union all
    select id, description, null, 'B' from tableb
) dt
group by id, description
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for Oracle database.
Maybe it can help...

```
select coalesce(a.id1, b.id2) as ID,
       coalesce(a.description1, b.description2) as Description
        , (case 
             when a.id1 = b.id2 then 'Table A+B'
             when b.id2 not in (select id1 from a) then 'Table B'
             else 'Table A'
        end) as Usage
from a full join b
on nvl(a.id1, b.id2) = b.id2;
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56232/1